# how to make HTML column-oriented and div based table's height same in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html-table

I am implementing a column-oriented & div based table with React with Typescript, which is rendered by  data outside table. this data are structured column based. for example it renders column 1 and then row 1, row 2 , row 3 and column 2 then row 1, row 2, row ..and so on

The problem is the height of a cell differs when one of cells is higher than others
However I would like this custom div based table work like html table tag with same height

How can i make height of cells in each rows same when height of cells in each row differ ?

i want the height of cells in each row to be set highest height among cells in each row if all height of cells differ in the row

[current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzflR.png)

[my expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX4mw.png)

[react tag structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgFI3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML structure is a bit wrong.

```css
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100px;
}
.header{
    display: table-cell;    
}
.row {
    display: table-row; 
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="header">Header</div>
        <div class="header">Header</div>
        <div class="header">Header</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="cell">cell adasd dadad wd rwr r ewrewrrere</div>
        <div class="cell">cell</div>
        <div class="cell">cell</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="cell">cell</div>
        <div class="cell">cell</div>
        <div class="cell">cell</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: HTML table in my app renders column first. for example 
It renders first column first and then first row 1 in column 1, row 2 in column 1 , row 3 in column 1 and then row 1 in column 2, row 2 in column 2 , row 3 in column 2

However your tag renders row first such as column 1 ,column 2, column 3 in row 1 , column 1 ,column 2, column 3 in row 2... 

Mine is opposite